# Watin-Find records of java applet in HTML Page 

Tags: watin

I want to retrive data one by one in **java applet** in HTML using **watin** but I doesn't find these records.Actul scenario is https://i.stack.imgur.com/984Ry.png .

Page Source is following but I want to read record like https://i.stack.imgur.com/984Ry.png

< applet name="view" code="lotus.notes.apps.viewapplet.ViewApplet.class" codebase="/domjava" archive="nvapplet.jar" alt="View" width="100%" height="100%" mayscript >

< param name="cabbase" value="nvapplet.cab" >
< param name="Database" value="repairnet/ConConnect.nsf" >
< param name="ViewName" value="Web Views\Open Claims" >
< param name="PanelStyle" value="LINE_BORDER" >
< param name="ViewUNID" value="03CE72869B6C38E080257670003A0721" >
< param name="ShowSelectionMargin" value="FALSE" >
< param name="Expand" value="TRUE" >
< param name="bgColor" value="#FFFFFF" >
< param name="RestrictToCategory" value="Marshgate%20Builders%20Ltd" >
< param name="locale" value="en-us,en" >
< param name="IconPath" value="/icons" >
< /applet >

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

WatiN is only able to read html/the DOM. Your data seems to be inside the java applet, which WatiN can't read.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your warm response Jeroen.  But is there any other way to read a data from java applet ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the browser console, anything you can do there can be done with WatiN using the browser eval method.  In your case, if you can run

```
$("applet[name='view']").innerHtml
```

from the browser's console (inspect element console), you should be able to add this line to the WatiN test.  Just make sure you backslash out any of the quotes inside of your eval as I have done.

```
string params = Browser.Eval("$(\"applet[name='view']\").innerHtml")
```

From there, you could parse the params and iterate through each name/value line in the string.

Alternatively, if inspect element shows the applet inline with the rest of the html (perhaps in the < head >), you should be able to grab it via the page class element getters.  From there, you can still interact with it.

```
[FindBy(Name = 'view')]
public Element myApplet { get; set; }
```

Search WatiN's documentation on page classes for more info on that.